# Trouble with setting cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, cookies, internet-explorer-9

this is a section of my script:

```
session_start();
echo '<p>Initiated...';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<p>Executed...';
if ($_POST['username'] == $un && $pw == md5($_POST['password'])) {

    $_SESSION['user'] = 'admin';
    echo '<p>Success...';



$value = 'admin';

setcookie("user2", $value);
setcookie("user2", $value, time()+36000);  /* expire in 1000 hours */
setcookie("user2", $value, time()+36000, "/", "my.domain.net", 1);

echo 'Hello!'.$_COOKIE["user2"];
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["user2"];
}
}
```

It works perfectly in FireFox, Chrome and Safari, however it will not work in Internet Explorer as it does not seem to be setting cookies. The output in Internet Explorer is:

Initiated...

Executed...

Success...Hello!

**In Chrome/Safari/FireFox:**

Initiated...

Executed...

Success...Hello!admin

Settings in Internet Explorer are set to accept all cookies .. I'm really stuck on this. :( please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following after the `session_start()`

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
```

Comment: Nope that didnt help at all :(